# Testing with CDI, mocking a bean

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

I am wondering how i am doing tests with CDI. and mocking classes during injection.

if i have the class:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ItemProcessor {

  @Inject
  private ItemDao itemDao;


  public void execute() {


    List<Item> items = itemDao.fetchItems();
    for (Item item : items) {
        System.out.println("Found item " + item);
    }
  }
}
```

How do i do if i want to mock the ItemDao class during test, when i want to test My ItemProcessor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could - for example - use CDI "Alternatives".

```
@Alternative
public class TestCoderImpl implements Coder { ... }
```

Now, this bean will only be used if it is declared in your beans.xml as an alternative.

```
<alternatives>
    <class>package.TestCoderImpl</class>
</alternatives>
```

Further [info](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html).

Comment: Can i have my normal bean without the @Alternative annotation and just do the <altnernatives/> during test?

Comment: Sure, your normal bean wouldn't have the @Alternative annotation, your test bean would have it. You could activate your alternative bean by placing the mentioned tag in your beans.xml.

Comment: Is it possible todo the samething on just a @Produce method?

Comment: Well, you could create a bean in your producer method based on a condition, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html). Or, there is a more advanced solution [here](http://marcus-schulte.blogspot.hu/2012/12/globally-configurable-wiring.html).

Answer (score 4):

Frameworks, like mockito, can set dependencies to mocks even when using field injection: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

In general, however, constructor injection is preferred for this exact reason: testability.

Comment: Thanks for the help but where more looking for what Csaba awnsered.

Comment: I think your comment about constructor injection is the best part of this answer.